# Gesture recognizer is not working on UIView

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get a few gesture recognisers to work on a UIView. The UIview is in this case a retrieved SVG image, the library that I use is SwiftSVG.

But the actual added image is a UIView, so I think that is not the problem?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let svgURL = URL(string: "https://openclipart.org/download/181651/manhammock.svg")!
    let hammock = UIView(SVGURL: svgURL) { (svgLayer) in
        svgLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red:0.8, green:0.16, blue:0.32, alpha:1.00).cgColor
        svgLayer.resizeToFit(self.v2imageview.bounds)

    }
    hammock.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
    hammock.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
    hammock.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.view.addSubview(hammock)

}
    // function which is triggered when handleTap is called
    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Hello World")
    }
```

How can I make the recognizer work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a frame

```
hammock.frame = ///
```

or constraints